# Using "clout" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-patterns

I want to use it in this context :

> Group A has a lot of influence on organization B.

Should it be :

> Group A has a lot of clout with organization B.

?

Comment: A synonym of "clout" is "influence". For example, if you have political clout it means that you have political power or influence.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of *clout* here is the second one from this list:

- pull; strong influence; muscle, especially political power

So the example sentence given there applies:

- a wealthy campaign contributor with clout at city hall.

So your sentence is correct.